# position:fixed - difference in firefox and chrome

Tags: css, menu, css-position, sticky, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using [Skeleton boilerplate](http://www.getskeleton.com/) to create a responsive design.

This is how it looks in Chrome and Firefox respectively

Chrome: http://screensnapr.com/v/iaXYDS.jpg

Firefox: http://screensnapr.com/v/EW6HZM.jpg

as you can see, the gray bar which is supposed to be the menu looks fine in chrome. what i am trying to achieve is a sticky menu which is relatively fixed within its parent.

here's the css for the #menu (gray bar)

```
#menu {
    z-index: 1000;
    background: #666;
    position: fixed;
}
```

Here is the class of the #menu using the Skeleton boilerplate.

```
<div id="menu" class="sixteen columns">
```

Which will in give the #menu these following styles

```
.container .sixteen.columns {
    width: 940px;
}

.container .column, .container .columns {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You can test it through this URL

http://home.piratelufi.com/sticky/

and download the source code (sorry for the cluttered files)

http://home.piratelufi.com/sticky/sticky.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Remove** to `display : inline` in **your css**

```
.container .column, .container .columns{
display:inline; // remove this line 
}
```

Because **you define** `float:left;`

Comment: than u add the display:block;

Comment: could you please explain why firefox displays it awkwardly?

Comment: i actually forced display:block on the element itself so i wont be changing the skeleton boilerplate

Comment: @kapitanluffy to this css file http://home.piratelufi.com/sticky/skeleton/stylesheets/skeleton.css line no 25 and remove this or add display:block;

Comment: @dmi3y can you cite a better reference about what your saying?

Comment: Sure, as soon as I get my desktop)

Comment: @kapitanluffy, here is sample with short explanation of my thoughts http://jsbin.com/ubijel/1/edit

Comment: Even `display:inline-block` causes the same problem